# Is &"string" the same address as "string"?

Tags: c, string, memory-address, c-strings

I have some generated C code that looks like this:

```
char *example[] = {&" ",&"\n", &"\t"};
```

If I were to write this myself, I would drop the ampersands (&), as string literals are already of type `char *`.  To me, it looks like `example` *should* have been generated declared as a `char**[]`.

Can I be sure that the pointer is the same with or without the `&`s?  Is this taking the address of an address well defined in C?

Edit: I am investigating a warning on some software currently in a lifecycle that doesn't accept any changes.  Is `printf("%p", &"hello world");` always the same as `printf("%p", "hello world");`, or is this dependent on the compiler?

Comment: This is extremely confused on many counts. String literals are not "already of type `char *` at all, in several ways. And taking the address of the string literal is not the same thing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that a string literal is not an *address* (type `char *`), but an *array* (type `char[]`) or *array initializer* (for type `char[]`). Of course, an array *can* decay to a pointer, but it doesn't *have* to.

Comment: If you spent the extra money on a good compiler, you would have gotten useful warnings that would have saved you a lot of time.

Comment: You need to fix the "generator" of this code (or insert your own preprocessing layer to fix it up).

Comment: I am currently investigating a warning to see how severe it is.  I would love to do all of the above to fix it, but the software is currently in a lifecycle that doesn't accept any changes to compiler, software, etc.

Comment: @Darthfett regarding your edit, would you mind to add these new questions in a new SO question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is &“string” the same address as “string”?

No, their type is different.

```
 "hello world"
```

object has type `char [12]`. As for other arrays in an expression context, it is converted to `char *`.

But:

```
 &"hello world"
```

has type `char (*)[12]`.

So in your example, it also means that:

```
char *example[] = {&" ",&"\n", &"\t"};
```

is an invalid declaration as the array elements in the initializer list are not of type `char *`.

This is the correct declaration:

```
char *example[] = {" ", "\n", "\t"};
```

for the sake of this question, if you had to use the `&`, here is the correct declaration:

```
char (*example[3])[] = {&" ",&"\n", &"\t"};
```

Comment: So the correct declaration would be `char *example[][]`?  Is `printf("%p", &"hello world")` always the same as `printf("%p", "hello world")`, or is this undefined?

Comment: Essentially correct, but it's not clear what "expression context" means, or how the operand to unary `&` is not in such a context. The array-to-pointer conversion occurs *unless* the array expression is (a) the operand of unary `&`; (b) the operand of `sizeof`, or (c) a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array object.

Comment: @Darthfett: No, the correct declaration would probably be `char *example[] = {" ", "\n", "\t"};`. `printf("%p", ...)` requires an argument of type `void*`. You can almost certainly get away with passing a `char*`, and you can *probably* get away with passing a `char(*)[12]`, but you should cast to `void*` just to be sure. Your to `printf` calls should print the same thing *if* the two occurrences of `"hello world"` are merged in memory; compilers may do this, but they're not required to.

Comment: @Darthfett The correct declaration would be `char (*example[])[2] = {&" ",&"\n", &"\t"};` as long as every pointed-to string literal in `example` is 2 characters long (one character plus the null terminator), as is the case in your example.

Comment: Certainly the same address, though due to type a different pointer / value.

Comment: @KeithThompson regarding the three exceptions, this kind of questions comes up often on SO and I'm lazy to not to always mention the whole story. Thanks for summarizing it in the comment.